# SQL how do I INSERT INTO a tables from other seperate tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to insert values into a table ,with values coming from separate tables as well as a php file,but i also need there to be a where clause. I have no idea how to do this so any help would be appriated.

The current SQL to get an idea whats going on is:

****INSERT INTO order1(Order_ID,Supplier_ID,Product_ID,Stock_Amount,Reorder_Time,Postcode   Amount_Ordered,Telephone_Number)
VALUES(product.product_ID,:supplier_ID,product.Stock_Amount,:stockamount,supplier.Reorder_Time,
supplier.Postcode,:Amount_Ordered,supplier.Telephone_Number)
WHERE product.product_ID=:product_ID****

(:Variable is just some data being passed into by a php file and product and supplier are just other tables)

The code doesnt need to be efficient it just needs to work,
Any help is very much appricitated

Comment: `INSERT`s do not have a `WHERE` clause, so what are you trying to do, exactly? Are you trying to use the new ID _after_ the INSERT to use with the other tables to insert references? If so, check into `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could phrase this as an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```sql
INSERT INTO order1 (Order_ID, Supplier_ID, Product_ID, Stock_Amount,
                    Reorder_Time, Postcode, Amount_Ordered, Telephone_Number)

SELECT product_ID, :supplier_ID, Stock_Amount, :stockamount, Reorder_Time, Postcode,
       :Amount_Ordered, Telephone_Number
FROM order1
WHERE product_ID = :product_ID;
```